# Formatar arquivo RTF para ser enviado como body utilizando o MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, email, rtf

Tenho que enviar um relatório em texto (com formatação) que coloquei em um arquivo RTF dentro do meu projeto.

Quando vou definir o body do email utilizando o método abaixo, a formatação do arquivo RTF não é reconhecida pelo MFMailComposeViewController.

Segue código que estou utilizando e a NSString retornada do meu arquivo RTF:

```obj-c
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"relatorio"
                                                 ofType:@"rtf"];

NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
```

Já tentei vários encodings e não alterou o conteúdo do emailBody, segue abaixo o começo da NSString emailBody:

```rtf
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1265
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural\qc

\f0\b\fs24 \cf0 Relat\'f3rio \
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural
\cf0 Desenvolvido por Finaltap\
```

Colocar em HTML não é uma opção pois o relatório é muito grande e foi retirado de um arquivo MS Word.

Alguma idéia???

Answer (score 1):

A idéia mais simples é enviar como anexo. Se você não tem necessidade de fazer alterações em tempo de execução, é uma solução extremamente simples e deve resolver seu problema.

Você vai iniciar um `NSData`com o conteúdo do arquivo e passar ele no `addAttachmentData` do `picker`. Feito!

Agora se você realmente precisa colocar o conteúdo diretamente no corpo do email, acredito que serão necessárias algumas conversões para `HTML`. Você diz que alterar o arquivo de origem não é uma opção, mas vou citar a possibilidade de fazer essa conversão em runtime.

O `NSAttributedString` possui um `initWithData` que suporta receber um `NSData` de um arquivo `RTF`. Após a conversão, provavelmente você será capaz de obter o texto em attributed strings ou até mesmo em `HTML`, se trabalhar corretamente com o output gerado.